# Failed to create provisioning profile no found a good solution

Tags: ios, xcode

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtnKS.jpg)

Already review other questions and no found solution to this error, someone can help me! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem recently. Please go to [Apple Developer site](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/device/)'s "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" part, go to the Devices > All section and add a new iPhone there with the UUID & name, then click on Try Again in XCode. Or simply follow the instructions, plug in an iOS device and select it in XCode, so it can automatically register the device for you and create the provisioning profile.

Comment: thanks for your answer, already did that solution, in the section Apple Developer site's no find this option Devices > All section and add a new iPhone there with the UUID & name, I have pay as developer for this? thanks for your help!